# if-else-if javascript returns true and exits regardless of input

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

I have been trying desperately to figure out the syntax for using multiple else-if statements in javascript for a long time, and after about three hours reading and testing, I feel like I've pretty much hit a wall.

```
javascript:
var n = prompt("please enter number");
if (n = 2) { 
    window.alert("b") 
} else { 
    if (n = 1) { 
        window.alert("a") 
    } else { 
        window.alert("other") 
    } 
};
```

From everything I've read, the above code **should** work, but very time I run it the output results in a "b" alert no matter what I use for input. I've tried several different variations of this trying to find the correct syntax, but nothing has worked so far.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
if (n = 2) {
```

You need:

```
if (n === "2")
```

Or less preferably:

```
if (n == 2) {
```

Same with all the other statements. Currently you are assigning not comparing.

Comment: `if (n === "2") {` might be more appropriate, unless the OP specifically wants the wacky behavior of ==.

Comment: @ThomSmith very good point, updated my answer thanks.